# Book where Patton or MacArthur teams up with Robert E.Lee in an apocalyptic world

Tags: story-identification, books, alternate-history, apocalypse

A friend told me he read an excellent SF book years ago where Patton or maybe MacArthur partnered somehow with Robert E. Lee in a near-future apocalyptic world. Who knows this?

Comment: I passed your answer along to my friend, who says this isn't it, regrettably. Thanks so much for your answer.  Update: My friend thinks the book was released around 1993.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a longshot, but *[Mars Needs Books!](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13222010-mars-needs-books-a-science-fiction-novel)* by Gary Lovisi mentions using those generals for mental templates.

[image: Image of page from Google Books]

[image: Front cover of Mars Needs Books!]

> In the not-so-distant future, men have come to Mars to escape the oppressive Earth government. Ryan is an agent for a super-secret government agency, the Department of Control (DOC), and has always been willing to do whatever his masters want of him. But on Mars, everything is different, and all that Ryan does is read books: hardboiled, noir crime paperbacks dating from the last century. In fact, such works are read and collected by everyone on Mars, even serving as a medium of exchange. Why? Is there some secret DOC plot involved? Or has Ryan conjured up a literary fantasy in his own guilt-twisted mind? Maybe he's still confined in a prison cell back on Earth, reading a science-fiction novel called Mars Needs Books! As Ryan probes deeper and deeper into the mystery, he comes to understand just one thing: he must uncover the truth!